# Detect open sockets manually (not using nc or similar)?

Tags: networking, filesystems, socket

I'm trying to debug a network problem on an embedded system which has a very limited set of user space applications. That is, I can't use any of the following

```bash
sudo lsof -i
sudo netstat -lptu
sudo netstat -tulpn
```

How can I read which sockets are bound from `/sys` or `/proc`?

Answer (score 4):

Netstat and lsof get their information from `/proc/$pid/fd/*` for per-process data and from `/proc/net/tcp`, `/proc/net/udp`, `/proc/net/icmp` and `/proc/net/raw` for IPv4 socket information (and `/proc/net/tcp6`, `/proc/net/udp6` and `/proc/net/raw6` for IPv6). The equivalent of your commands is mostly to read these files in `/proc/net` (plus DNS lookups).

For debugging purposes, consider uploading a binary of `lsof` to your system, it can be a lot more convenient than rummaging in `/proc`.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the list of binded sockets from /proc/net/tcp[6], /proc/net/udp[6] and /proc/net/raw[6].

Beware if converting the hex values in those files to "normal" IP adresses, they are in little-endian (e.g. 3900060A represents 10.6.0.57 and not 57.0.6.10 as least significant byte comes first).